# Can't get shaft into transmission

Tags: transmission, mitsubishi, axle, cv-joint

I have a 2WD drive 2012 Mitsubishi Outlander SE 2.4... I have been frustrated trying to get this part in for 2 days. I am trying to replace my CV axle but for the life of me, I cannot get this shaft piece back in my car.

It is a shaft that connects the transmission to the CV axle and is about a foot long with male splines on both ends. It is the original that slid out of my transmission, so I know it should fit.

Things I've tried:

- Hitting it in with a rubber and steel hammer
- Turning it spline by spline
- Pushing as hard as I can

I am concerned that the splines are damaged. This piece should slide right into the transmission and not need excessive force, right? Any advice is appreciated.

[image: Shaft and transmission]

[image: Shaft]

[image: axle]

Comment: Welcome to Motor Vehicle Maintenance & Repair! I'm wondering if this is one of those things which someone would have to be there to help you figure it out. I don't see any damage which would preclude it from going in. The only thing I'd suggest is to ensure the shaft is COMPLETELY straight to the transaxle while trying to insert it. Any angle off and you're going to have problems

Comment: Potentially... would you recommend having a mechanic come out and looking at it or having the car towed to a shop? Thanks for your thoughts.

Comment: In the second picture, does it look like the splined female gear is out of position? It doesn't look centered to me (but it may be the angle of the image). See if you can move it to center (if it is out of center).

Comment: It does look like the female side is misaligned

Comment: These do require some force to put in. the ring on the end can make these hard to do.

Comment: Try take a wire brush and brush both ends of the male and  female splines

Answer (score 1):

OK I was able to get everything to work out. I looked all over the internet and that shaft part is impossible to replace. I even looked into ordering it from Japan. It is a MOPAR export part that seems to be discontinued.

Anyway, I took my damaged part to a mechanic. He was able to file and sand down the splines. I used some lubrication and I was able to get it into the transmission.

Lesson learned... Use a soft metal hammer when trying to hammer pieces in and be very careful to make sure the splines are straight for next time.

Comment: Please don't use a hammer or force at all to fit (splined) shafts. They should slide in effortlessly until the seal. Push somewhat to insert it in the seal. If you can't seem to slide it in at first, turn and wiggle a bit and try again. Make sure the splines and the seal stay clean from any dirt.